# Is there a notion of a tenant name within an MS Teams bot context or function?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

In botbuilder, there's a `context.activity.channelData` object that my bot received. That has a `tenant` object which only contains an `id` property. Is there any property or function that can return to me the name of the tenant (organization) who belongs to that `id`?

Here's an example. A user works for `Acme Inc.` and has three MS Teams teams: Team1, Team2, and Team3. I can get the names of all the teams, and I can get the `tenantId` for "Acme Inc." but how can I get the name of the tenant that owns those team, a.k.a. the text `Acme Inc.`?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't get that info from channelData.

You can use GraphAPI to return the org name. 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization?$select=displayName`

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) is a bot sample on how to use graph in a bot. And [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) is a sample on using auth in Teams. With all that together, you should be able to get that info.

If needed at all you can get the AAD group ID from TeamsInfo. Info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-teams-details).

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to get the actual tenant name per se from channel data, what *you* can do in your bot is make a call to get "conversation members", in order to get a UPN for the user(s). Here's an [example in C#](https://doumer.me/get-user-info-with-your-chat-bot-in-microsoft-teams/) (I'm sure there's a Node equivalent) an that will give you properties including:

```
"userPrincipalName": "MeganB@[whatever].OnMicrosoft.com"
```

That might be enough for what you need?